# package appended when debugging android intentService

Tags: android, package, intentservice, malformed

Have searched and not found an answer needed for debugging an IntentService.
When calling Intent x = new Intent (context, xyz.class) the debugger shows that the intent{cmp= line read cmp=package.name.**test**/package.name.class which can't be resolved in the manifest.

Do I need to have a debug manifest to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();`
 sets the packagename in the context to packagename.test which is the reason that my IntentService could not be found.